# How to train a neural network using validation in Matlab

Tags: matlab, validation

I'm trying to show the difference between results of an ANN trained with and without validation...

assume that I'm trying to train a ANN how a sin function should work:

this is gonna be my training data:

```
x = -1:0.05:1;
t = sin(2*pi*x)+0.01*randn(size(x));
```

and for validation data I gonna use this:

```
val.X = -0.975:.05:0.975;
val.T = sin(2*pi*val.X)+0.01*randn(size(val.X));
```

then I configure my net as follows:

```
net = feedforwardnet(10,'trainlm');
net.trainParam.show = 50;
net.trainParam.epochs = 300;
```

then I train net without validation :

```
[net1, tr1] = train(net,x,t);
```

and for training with validation I use this code:

```
[net2,tr2]=train(net,x,t,[],[],val);
```

but it doesn't work!?

**EDIT**:

the error says: "Error weights EW is not a matrix or cell array."

I wonder if you could tell me how to validate training ANN by custom data!?

Comment: It doesnt work? Does you computer explode? What hapens. Why doesnt it work?

Comment: well the error says: "Error weights EW is not a matrix or cell array."

Comment: Looking at the documentation here, http://www.mathworks.com/help/nnet/ref/train.html, the 6th input to the `train` function is supposed to be a matrix of error weights. You are feeding in your `val` array. Are you sure you're using the function correctly?

Comment: honestly, using train method like this was regular in matlab2010 when we use newff function to configure ANN, but now if you use newff for configuring the ANN then it accept train function as it shown above using 7th argument for inserting Val data but now, in matlab2014, with feedforwardnet function for configuring ANN it is not working ... I wonder if you could tell me how to validate the training by custom data.